# caldav on iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, caldav

Is there a way to interact with a caldav server with the iPhone sdk.

Answer (score 1):

it may not possible to use the existing API to do so. But the user can set the connection in the following steps.

1) setting

2) mail, contacts, calendar

3) add account...

4) other

5) add CalDav account